# Modify existing pdf document with php

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

So what I would like to do is pretty straight forward, I would like to modify an existing pdf document.

Instead of writing to an existing pdf where I added, it writes to a blank file.

Here is the code.

```
<?php

require('vendor/autoload.php');

$mpdf = new mPDF();

$mpdf->AddPage();
// set the sourcefile
$mpdf->setSourceFile('hs.pdf');
// import page 1
$tplIdx = $mpdf->importPage(1);
// use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 200 mm   (This is the image of the included pdf)
$mpdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 200);
// now write some text above the imported page
$mpdf->SetTextColor(0,0,255);

$mpdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
$mpdf->SetXY(95, 16);
$mpdf->Write(0, "Mindfire");
$mpdf->Output('newpdf.pdf');
```

This is the image I want to write to.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzIZT.png)

Add this is the image it outputs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLiFi.png)

As you can see it seems to be just writing to a blank document every time instead of writing the the first pdf.

Any ideas ?

Update:

Here is my composer.json file

```
 {
  "require": {
    "mpdf/mpdf": "v5.5.1"
  }
}
```

Ive tried all different verison of mpdf but the same error persists.

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found in
```

Comment: From your code, this should be erroring. since it should be `$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf()`, unless you are using mPDF version `<= 6.0` where that class name was valid, in which case you are missing the call for [`$mpdf->SetImportUse()`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setimportuse.html) or a [full example](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setsourcefile.html)

Comment: using $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf() gives me "Uncaught Error: Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found in" and when I use $mpdf = new \mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L'); I installed mpdf with composer, not sure what I am missing here..

Comment: I switched my verison to the ^v8.0.13 and I am still getting Uncaught Error: Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found in, no matter the version its still not being found, I think if I solve that the rest is okay, I copy the example you showed me.

Comment: Sounds like PHP has the original source in OPcache. You may need to [clear it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-reset.php) in your environment before and/or after running `composer dump-autoload` for use  `new \Mpdf\Mpdf()` in version 7.0+. Would need to see composer.json and possible phpinfo() to determine what might be causing the failure.

Comment: Just updated the what I have in the composer.json file and I tried using composer dump-autoload but still no changes...

Comment: Please post your entire composer.json contents so we can see the other settings to see if there may be a conflict.  `v5.5.1` would be [`new mPDF();`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpdf/mpdf/v5.5.1/mpdf.php) with no namespace. and you would need to use [`$mpdf->SetImportUse();`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setsourcefile.html)

Comment: That is my entire composer.json file, I tried added a composer file that I found [here](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/blob/development/composer.json)

Comment: Each composer.json is specific to the functionality it provides, so I do not advise copying the source of another project and expect it to work for your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there has been some confusion surrounding the mPDF version syntax and composer usage. 
Since you've tried some ill-advised workarounds, I suggest resetting the composer environment and [Reinstalling mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/installation-v7-x.html).

**Set the project directory as your CWD**

```sh
cd /path/to/project
```

**Delete the composer managed files**

Linux OS

```sh
rm -rf ./vendor
rm ./composer.json
rm ./composer.lock
```

Windows OS cmd

```sh
rmdir /Q /S .\vendor
del .\composer.json
del .\composer.lock
```

Windows OS PowerShell

```sh
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force .\vendor
Remove-Item .\composer.json
Remove-Item .\composer.lock
```

**Reinstall mPDF library files**

```sh
composer require mpdf/mpdf
```

**Your project directory should contain the following:**
Where *pdf_creator.php* is the script used to generate the PDF.

```
project/
   composer.json
   hs.pdf
   pdf_creator.php
   vendor/
      mpdf/
      autoload.php
      ...
```

**Check the version of mPDF in your composer.json file**
Depending on the version use one of the examples below.

```json
{
    "require": {
        "mpdf/mpdf": "^8.0"
    }
}
```

### mPDF 4.3 to 6.x

Method names use ***pascal-cased*** pattern
No namespace
Classname is `mPDF()`

Example: [example41_MPDFI_template.php](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/blob/v6.1.4/examples/example41_MPDFI_template.php)

```
<?php
/* pdf_creator.php */

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new mPDF();

// set the sourcefile
$mpdf->SetImportUse(); // <--- required for mPDF versions < 8.0
$mpdf->SetSourceFile(__DIR__ . '/hs.pdf'); // absolute path to pdf file

// import page 1
$tplIdx = $mpdf->ImportPage(1);

// use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 200 mm   (This is the image of the included pdf)
$mpdf->UseTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 200);

// now write some text above the imported page
$mpdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 255);
$mpdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);
$mpdf->SetXY(95, 16);
$mpdf->Write(0, 'Mindfire');
$mpdf->Output('newpdf.pdf');
```

### mPDF 7.x

Method names use ***pascal-cased*** pattern
Introduced the \Mpdf namespace
Classname is `Mpdf()`

Example [Importing Files & Templates](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/importing-files-templates.html)

```
<?php
/* pdf_creator.php */

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

// set the sourcefile
$mpdf->SetImportUse(); // <--- required for mPDF versions < 8.0
$mpdf->SetSourceFile(__DIR__ . '/hs.pdf'); // absolute path to pdf file

// import page 1
$tplIdx = $mpdf->ImportPage(1);

// use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 200 mm   (This is the image of the included pdf)
$mpdf->UseTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 200);

// now write some text above the imported page
$mpdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 255);
$mpdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);
$mpdf->SetXY(95, 16);
$mpdf->Write(0, 'Mindfire');
$mpdf->Output('newpdf.pdf');
```

### mPDF 8.x

Method names use ***camel-cased*** pattern
Introduced the \Mpdf namespace
Classname is `Mpdf()`
Method `Mpdf::SetImportUse()` was removed

Example [Importing Files & Templates](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/importing-files-templates.html)

```
<?php
/* pdf_creator.php */

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

// set the sourcefile
// $mpdf->SetImportUse(); // <--- not needed for mPDF version 8.0+
$mpdf->setSourceFile(__DIR__ . '/hs.pdf'); // absolute path to pdf file

// import page 1
$tplIdx = $mpdf->importPage(1);

// use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 200 mm   (This is the image of the included pdf)
$mpdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 200);

// now write some text above the imported page
$mpdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 255);
$mpdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);
$mpdf->SetXY(95, 16);
$mpdf->Write(0, 'Mindfire');
$mpdf->Output('newpdf.pdf');
```

Now run your script from the CLI to see it emits any errors.

```sh
cd /path/to/project
php pdf_creator.php
```

---

**Note**

- `$mpdf->AddPage();` is not needed for editing a PDF file, unless
  adding another page to the resulting output PDF.

Comment: Thank you Will, you made that look easy. This is working perfectly, God Bless.